# How to perform SMOTE-N when there is no majority vote?

Tags: feature-selection, categorical-data, class-imbalance, smote

In the [SMOTE paper](https://www.jair.org/media/953/live-953-2037-jair.pdf), the authors present the logic of creating synthetic examples when all features are nominal (section 6.2, SMOTE-N):

> To generate new minority class feature vectors, we can create new set
>   feature values by taking the majority vote of the feature vector in
>   consideration and its k nearest neighbors

Along with this example:

> Let F1 = A B C D E be the feature vector under consideration and let
>   its 2 nearest neighbors be
>
> F2 = A F C G N
>
> F3 = H B C D N
>
> The
>   application of SMOTE-N would create the following feature vector: FS =
>   A B C D N

How would FS be chosen in the case that `F3 = H B C I N`? How does Value Difference Metric by Cost and Salzberg described in the paper assist in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what "VDM" stands for, but a simple solution for tie breaking is to randomly pick one of the tied options.

Comment: Edited my question - VDM: Value Difference Metric by Cost and Salzberg described in the paper. See the paper by C&S: http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~bylander/cs6243/cost93weighted.pdf

Comment: I guess I'll have to email the authors of the paper.. in the meantime, your answer seems legit :)